# Is it possible to add multiple section Names for a particular section in INI files

Tags: c#, ini

I would like to know whether we have any chance of adding multiple section names for a particular section in an INI file.

For eg,

```
[Section1]
[Section2]
key = value
key1 = value1
```

If it is possible, the can any one help me to get the "value2" by passing "Section1" name in c#.

Comment: Why are you still using INI files? This isn't the 90s anymore :)

Comment: I know buddy :) It's a maintenance code which was almost 30 yrs old.. :)

Comment: Not possible by using available implementations, but nobody hinders you to write your own ini-parser that supports that format. ;-)

Comment: Nobody's forcing you to keep using this when refactoring. Just make a separate class / methods to give you exactly what you want, and let that single method handle whatever you need to handle. Abstraction is the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The INI file format is extremely simple, and only has two levels of keys - the section name, and the actual key. It's just a very simple key-value store.

You simply defined an empty configuration section `Section1`, and then a `Section2` with two keys, `key` and `key1`.